# What is the purpose of Unit-returning in functions

Tags: kotlin

From the Kotlin documentation:

If a function does not return any useful value, its return type is Unit. Unit is a type with only one value — Unit.VALUE. This value does not have to be returned explicitly:

```
fun printHello(name : String?) : Unit { 
   if (name != null) 
     print("Hello, $name!") 
   else 
     print("Hi there!") 
   // We don't need to write 'return Unit.VALUE' or 'return', although we could 
}
```

What is the purpose of Unit-returning in functions? Why is VALUE there? What is this VALUE?

Comment: I am no category theory expert but AFAIK the name `void` and `unit` comes from category theory. `void` is a category with no members,  `unit` is a category with one member, `bool` is a category with two members (true & false). `void` is inherited from C and it's a major hassle for generic code. Typically in Java, C# and C++ you need to handle the `void` case specifically because it's an odd type (it has no value). `unit` is subtly superior as it has one value meaning there's no need to for special cases. Also in FP all functions take 1 argument so you need a don't care value.

Comment: `Unit` exists because of Generic reasons and code can work smoothly. and also It  returns the information to the caller, that the method has been finished.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The purpose is the same as C's or Java's `void`. Only Unit is a proper type, so it can be passed as a generic argument etc.

1. Why we don't call it "Void": because the word "void" means "nothing", and there's another type, `Nothing`, that means just "no value at all", i.e. the computation did not complete normally (looped forever or threw an exception). We could not afford the clash of meanings.
2. Why Unit has a value (i.e. is not the same as Nothing): because generic code can work smoothly then. If you pass Unit for a generic parameter T, the code written for any T will expect an object, and there must be an object, the sole value of Unit.
3. How to access that value of Unit: since it's a singleton object, just say `Unit`

Comment: Thank you! I see the reason it is not Void or Nothing now. But choosing 'Unit' looks a little misleading for me.  I'm not a native English speaker though.

Comment: "Unit" just stands for "something that has only one value", it's a traditional name, comes from functional languages. I agree that this name is not very intuitive, but we failed to invent a better name.

Comment: @AndreyBreslav, sounds to me that the term `Unit` can't exist on it's, meaning "Unit of what?"

Comment: @AndreyBreslav, Yep [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1) leads to: "It represents a single entity, the unit of counting or measurement.". So what's the entity?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Actually, it isa tradition in functional world to call a type of 0-ary tuples "Unit", because it has only one value. I think it's a correct name, because according to the Wikipedia article the number "one" can also be called "unit" or "unity". You can think of it not as a unit of something, but as a unit type, i.e. a type that has the algebraic properties of 1 in the algebra of types. Look up "sum types" and "product types" for more details

Comment: Unit is in fact some kind of information. It basically means "done". This could be seen as the _implicit return value_ of a "void" method. We now have the information, that the method _has returned_.  Why Nothing gives you absolutely no information _at all_ because the method will never _return_ (e.g. endless loop).

Comment: if, "the sold value of Unit" is that is provides an Object, then why not call it Object.  If you want a distinct Object that only has one-single value (thus > Nothing), then call it ObjectOnlyNull.  The Language Architects just want to show off their prowess for describing the most esoteric, edge-case-of-an-edge-case that they can think of.  And to do it, they invent an unintuitive use of the English language.  May as well use Klingon for the reserved words.

Answer (score 21):

The main reason why Unit exists is because of Generic reasons.
Let's use the example from the Kotlin docs.

```
class Box<T>(t: T) {
    var value = t
}
```

We can have

```
var box = Box(Unit)
```

This is why Unit returns a value so the Kotlin can infer it from the type passed into class initialization. Of course, you could also explicitly write it like this,

```
var box = Box<Unit>(Unit)
```

but all the same, it must have a return value.
Now, the ***void*** keyword in Java in Kotlin is ***Nothing***. ***Nothing*** is the last but one type in the type hierarchy in Kotlin with the last one being ***Nothing?*** (Nullable Nothing). This does not return any value at all. Because it doesn't return any value at all, we can't pass it as a type in the above code.

```
var box = Box(Nothing) //This will return an Error
```

Answer (score 10):

`UNIT` actually contains valuable information, it basically just means "DONE". It just *returns* the information to the caller, that the method has been finished. This is a real piece of information so it can be seen as the *return value* of a method.