# What does Void return type mean in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, void, return-type

I tried to create function without returning value in Kotlin. And I wrote a function like in Java but with Kotlin syntax

```
fun hello(name: String): Void {
    println("Hello $name");
}
```

And I've got an error

> Error:A 'return' expression required in a function with a
>   block body ('{...}')

After couple of changes I've got working function with nullable Void as return type. But it is not exactly what I need

```
fun hello(name: String): Void? {
    println("Hello $name");
    return null
}
```

According to [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html) Unit type corresponds to the void type in Java. So the correct function without returning value in Kotlin is

```
fun hello(name: String): Unit {
    println("Hello $name");
}
```

Or

```
fun hello(name: String) {
    println("Hello $name");
}
```

The question is: What does `Void` mean in Kotlin, how to use it and what is the advantage of such usage?

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of Unit-returning in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22654932/435605)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Void` is a plain Java class and has no special meaning in Kotlin.

The same way you can use `Integer` in Kotlin, which is a Java class (but should use Kotlin's `Int`). You correctly mentioned both ways to not return anything. So, in Kotlin `Void` is "something"!

The error message you get, tells you exactly that. You specified a (Java) class as return type but you didn't use the return statement in the block.

Stick to this, if you don't want to return anything:

```
fun hello(name: String) {
    println("Hello $name")
}
```

Answer (score 37):

`Void` is an object in Java, and means as much as 'nothing'.
In Kotlin, there are specialized types for 'nothing':

- `Unit` -> replaces java's `void`
- `Nothing` -> 'a value that never exists'

Now in Kotlin you *can* reference `Void`, just as you can reference any class from Java, but you really shouldn't. Instead, use `Unit`. Also, if you return `Unit`, you can omit it.

Comment: `Void` (which is really: [`java.lang.Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)) is not an *object*, it's a *class* in Java. You can't make instances of this class.

Comment: @Jesper You can return `null`.