# What does nullable void mean in Kotlin?

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

If I generate callback code in android studio for a retrofit2 enqueue call I get

```
object : Callback<Void?> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void?>, response: Response<Void?>) {...}
    ...
}
```

The code in my retrofit2 interface is just `Void`

```
@POST("api/v1/users")
fun post(@Body body: UserRequestData): Call<Void>
```

Normally in Kotlin `?` just means nullable, which makes sense for other types.
But what is this type `Void?` and how is it different from just `Void` ?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-void-type

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834965/what-does-void-return-type-mean-in-kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Void.html):

> The `Void` class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the `Class` object representing the Java keyword void.

In general, `void` is replaced with [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/) in Kotlin.:

> The type with only one value: the `Unit` object. This type corresponds to the `void` type in Java.

However, when the use of `Void` is required due to it being used as a generic parameter, consider the following:

`Response<T>` has a function called `body()` that returns a generic `T`. In your case, For `Response<Void>.body()` it will [return `null`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/ee71a6858dfddcc4650f6ff4d71112911bdf6ca7/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Response.java#L151-L153). In Java, this is fine, because `Void` means "not relevant" so `null` is an appropriate response. But Kotlin has null-safetly, so to accurately represent that `null` is possible, `Response<Void?>` is necessary, even though it's slightly counter-intuitive.

A better design if the library was pure Kotlin would be `Response<Nothing>`, which should produce an error when you call `body()`.

Comment: "In general, Void is replaced with Unit in kotlin." No, only `void` is.

Comment: "A better design if the library was pure Kotlin would be Response<Nothing>, which should produce an error when you call body()." `Response<Unit>` would correspond better.