# What is Unit Object in Kotlin

Tags: jvm, kotlin

Right now I am learning Kotlin, in this [guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) I run into these two methods, one with`Unit` and another one doesn't

Method with`unit`

```
fun printSum(a: Int, b: Int): Unit {
  println("sum of $a and $b is ${a + b}")
}
```

Method without `Unit`

```
fun printSum(a: Int, b: Int) {
  println("sum of $a and $b is ${a + b}")
}
```

My question is, what is `Unit` do actually? is it something like `void` in Java? if it's like `void` why one of the method above doesn't have `Unit` run just fine.

which one should I use when I want my method returning nothing? And also when the best time to use `Unit`.

anyone can explain? cause it's really confusing me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great Question asked as if I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.It is clearly mentioned in the website as well as at the github source that

> `object Unit`
>   The type with only one value: the Unit object. This type corresponds to the **void type in Java**.

Also in the repository,

> /**
>    * The type with only one value: the Unit object. This type corresponds to the `void` type in Java.
>    */

[When to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44460059/7012517)

Comment: so what's the difference with the method without `Unit`, they both returning nothing

Comment: As a convenience Kotlin allows you to omit declaring the return type when the return type is Unit - see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions

Comment: @GustiArya No, it's specifically **not** returning nothing. Unit is an actual object.

Comment: No..as explained by @GregKopff, it is actually not returnig nothing....

Comment: @EJoshuaS so basically both method returning something?

Comment: @GustiArya `void` methods return nothing, `Unit` methods return something.

Comment: @GustiArya Yes, both your functions return the Unit object. There are no Kotlin functions that return nothing, but be careful, there are functions that return the type `Nothing` - which is way to tell the compiler that the function will never return. Both the `throw` and `return` statements are of that type. You can read more about that here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type

Comment: Also, what @EJoshuaS says is not quite true, `void` methods in Kotlin also return `Unit`, and not nothing.

Comment: @Hikaru755 I stand corrected on the `void` bit - obviously, Kotlin isn't my primary language :)

Comment: @GustiArya It's actually fairly common for languages to return something all the time - Scala and F# have the same exact thing. For example, in F#, every expression *must* return a value, so they included the `Unit` type if you don't care about the return value.

Comment: @Hikaru755 so all method in kotlin retuning a value even a `void` one, I just know that, that enlighten me up. thanks for your explanation